# Converting csv with one column separated by ; into the xlsm

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with one column with values separated by ';', I want to make it a nice to use xslm file with just the values in separate cells.

I read the file to obtain

```
read_file = pd.read_csv (r'2020_PM10_1g.csv',header=None)

                                                      0
0     2020-01-01 01:00; ; \t26.8\t; \t31.8\t; \t28.7...
1     2020-01-01 02:00; ; \t15.5\t; \t12.1\t; \t16.3...
2     2020-01-01 03:00; ; \t18.5\t; \t10.5\t; \t15.6...
3     2020-01-01 04:00; ; \t18.3\t; \t12.3\t; \t15.3...
4     2020-01-01 05:00; ; \t18.6\t; \t12.8\t; \t16.3...
```

Now how can I make it into a dataframe which has separate columns for each expression after ;, my desired output would be:

```
         0              1      2                            
0     2020-01-01 01:00     \t26.8\t ...
1     2020-01-01 02:00     \t15.5\t ...
2     2020-01-01 03:00     \t18.5\t ...
3     2020-01-01 04:00     \t18.3\t  ...
4     2020-01-01 05:00     \t18.6\t  ...
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv('2020_PM10_1g.csv', sep=';', header=None)`?

Comment: I tried it earlier, it returns the same dataframe with one column

Comment: Okay, it worked when I used as a delimiter '; ', weird that I had to add a space after semicolon

Comment: Not weird at all if the posted df actually does look like that. It is interpreted as a new separator ```; blank``` since both are separation methods.